# How to create custom composite entity select for Content?

Tags: webforms

Basically, I just need to show a custom composite containing a dropdown to the user which shows all the names of all published nodes of type 'product' so that they can choose as many as they want and see the final calculated price for the order.
Here's what I have so far in my custom composite php file:

```
$elements = [];
$elements['product_name'] = [
  '#type' => 'webform_entity_select',
  '#title' => t('Product Name'),
  '#target_type' => 'content',
  '#selection_handler' => 'default:content',
  '#attributes' => ['data-webform-composite-id' => $html_id . '--product-name'],
  '#selection_settings' => [
    'target_bundles' => [
      'product' => 'product'
    ],
    'sort' => [
      'field' => 'name',
      'direction' => 'ASC'
    ]
  ] 
];
$elements['yard_amount'] = [
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#title' => t('Amount (Yards)'),
];
$elements['bag_amount'] = [
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#title' => t('Amount (Bags)'),
];
```

The module is installed and the custom composite shows in the list, but when I add it, the dropdown is empty with no node titles shown.  The number fields show up fine.

Comment: I think `#target_type` would be `node` in this context. And the `#selection_handler` possibly `default:node` (although it looks like that's redundant if you set `#target_type` as it'll will default to `'default:' . $target_type`)

Comment: @Clive that was it, thank you so much!